# Am I applying the colorfilter in the right place in my custom ImageView?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm fairly new to creating my own custom views and `onDraw()` always strikes me as a scary place so I wanted to make sure I'm applying the color filter in the right place:

```
public class ColorImageView extends ImageView {

  private int mColor = -1;

  public ColorImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }
  public ColorImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ColorImageView);
    mColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.ColorImageView_customColor, -1);
    ta.recycle();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mColor != -1) {
      Util.applyColorFilter(getDrawable(), mColor);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDraw()` is not a place where you should perform heavy calculation. `onDraw()` will be called as many times as your view changes, every time it changes it will need to redraw itself and `onDraw()` called.

Move your color filtering inside `setImageDrawable()` after the super call. This method ensures that drawable will be drawn to the canvas and you can apply your color filter. `setImageDrawable` ensures that the `ImageView` will be invalidate once.

```
@Override
public void setImageDrawable(@NotNull drawable){
 super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
 applyColorFilter();
}
```

The best solution may be to call the applyColorFilter from both the constructor and this setImageDrawable().

Comment: Hmm the problem here though is that I'm getting the color from the attributes and from debugging, it seems `setImageDrawable()` is called before the constructor...as weird as that sounds.

Comment: Maybe super implementation of the `ImageView` constructor is call this method. That's probably because you are using `src` attribute in the xml.

Comment: Yeah I want to use the `src` attribute in the xml though - it seems the best solution is call the `applyColorFilter` from both the constructor and this `setImageDrawable()`?

Comment: Calling it in the constructor is fine, just after you resolve your custom color attr.

Answer (score 0):

That will work, but it would make more sense to apply it only when mColor is changed, and keep it set.  That way you don't need to continually reapply the filter each onDraw call, which is going to hit performance.

Comment: Could you suggest a better place for me to put it? I didn't want to set it in the constructor but didn't know what other lifecycle method to override for this